# Conversão de código está dando erro

Tags: c, c++

Estou tentando converter um código de C++ para C e surgiram dúvidas. O código começa assim:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

void function(int x, int y, int z,  char &teste, int *total)
```

Pensei de retirar o #include, o `namespace std` e colocar só:

```
#include <limits.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
```

Está correto? Ele dá um erro por causa do &teste. Pelo que eu deveria substituir??

Já troquei todos os `cout` e `cin`. Mais adiante no código, o compilador dá um erro em um `for`, e diz

> for loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode.

Porque ele não aceita o for normalmente? Isso ocorre, por exemplo, nestas linhas:

```
for (int i=1; i<n; i++) 
    senha[i][i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você terá varios problemas na conversão. o `char &teste` diz que a variável `teste` está sendo passado por referência, e C não permite esse tipo de coisa. Sendo assim você deverá converter a assinatura da função para:

```
void function(int x, int y, int z,  char *teste, int *total)
```

E todos os acessos a `teste` deverão ser substituidos por `(*teste)` (acesso a apontador).

Quanto ao erro a respeito da declaração do `int i=1` dentro do `for`, a razão disso é que o C padrão (C89) não aceita esse tipo de declaração, apenas as versões C99 ou superior. No compilador `gcc` você pode usar a flag `-std=c99` para especificar o uso dessa versão.

Answer (score 2):

Conversão pura e simples assim é perigosa, precisa entender o que está fazendo e todas implicações. Neste caso específico demonstrado basta trocar para ponteiro que resolverá o problema. Quebrará outras partes e terá que consertá-las. Mas novamente, não quer dizer que ficará tudo como quer. O maior problema que vejo no que quer fazer é a ingenuidade da ação em algo tão simples. Se você sabe C faça em C sem depender de conversão alguma de outra coisa.

O erro dor `for` é que tem que declarar a variável no início do código, mas é muito melhor configurar o compilador C para aceitar o C99 e não precisar fazer esta atrocidade.